# JWT FIPS compliance

Tags: spring, auth0, fips

I am developing on Spring framework and using auth0 for JWT authentication.
I find out some threads said that auth0 is not FIPS compliance, however I also find a thread said that RSA can be approved for digital signature.
auth0 is using RSA.
Should I change auth0 for FIPS compliance?
If yes, what options could I have?
Thank you.